# How to save output of subprocess.run into a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a `git` command that I am using

`git log --format=%H 3c2232a5583711aa5f37d0f21014934f67913202`

Here the long string at the end is the commit id. This command gives the list of previously commit ids of the branch. The output is like,

```
3c2232a5583711aa5f37d0f21014934f67913202
9i45e2a5583711aa5f37d0f21014934f679132de
```

I am trying to issue the same command in python and trying to store the output in a string as the following,

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(
    [
        "cd",
        "/Users/XYZ/Desktop/gitrepo",
        "git",
        "log",
        "3c2232a5583711aa5f37d0f21014934f67913202",
    ],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
)
print(result.stdout.decode("utf-8"), type(result.stdout.decode("utf-8")))
```

But the output of the print is empty! I tried `subprocess.run` with `["-ls", "-l"]` and it worked well. The git command works on command line but I am not able to capture it in a string. When I print the result alone,

```
CompletedProcess(args=['cd', '/Users/XYZ/Desktop/gitrepo', 'git', 'log', '3c2232a5583711aa5f37d0f21014934f67913202'], returncode=0, stdout=b'')
```

How can I save the git command's output in a string? I am issuing two commands in one line. Should I issue the commands separately? If I should then, how can I (a) navigate to git folder and (b) issue git command there?

Comment: you run two command in one line - `cd` and `git` - so it can execute only `cd` and use `git as argument for `cd`. And `cd` doesn't display any text.

Comment: @furas I see. How to run these two commands? : (1) navigate to git folder and (2) execute the git command?

Comment: You could create bash script with `cd` and `git` and run it in subprocess. You can also try to use `&&` to execute two commands - similar to `cd / && ls`

Comment: You could use the `C` option in git and skip changing directory. `git -C /Users/XYZ/Desktop/gitrepo log 3c2232a5583711aa5f37d0f21014934f67913202`

Comment: instead of `&&` you can also try `;` - similat to `cd / ; ls`

Comment: @micke worked great! thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your code runs `cd "/Users/XYZ/Desktop/gitrepo" "git" "log" "3c2232a5583711aa5f37d0f21014934f67913202"` which is probably not what you intended.

The best way is not to interpret changing the working directory as a separate command but as part of the setup of the environment to run the git command. [The subprocess module has the keyword argument `cwd` for that.](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

> If cwd is not None, the function changes the working directory to cwd
>   before executing the child. In particular, the function looks for
>   executable (or for the first item in args) relative to cwd if the
>   executable path is a relative path.

This is only documented for the Popen constructor but the `subprocess.run` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) has this paragraph:

> The arguments shown above are merely the most common ones, described
>   below in Frequently Used Arguments (hence the use of keyword-only
>   notation in the abbreviated signature). The full function signature is
>   largely the same as that of the Popen constructor - apart from
>   timeout, input and check, all the arguments to this function are
>   passed through to that interface.

So you can rewrite your code like this:

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(
    [
        "git",
        "log",
        "3c2232a5583711aa5f37d0f21014934f67913202",
    ],
    cwd="/Users/XYZ/Desktop/gitrepo"
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
)
print(result.stdout.decode("utf-8"), type(result.stdout.decode("utf-8")))
```